Where to generate OpenAPI types in a Spring Modulith application?
We're using the openapi-generator-maven-plugin to generate the interface layer and DTOs for our Spring Boot application.
Additionally we use Spring Modulith and domain driven application modules to structure our application.

we have our application modules within src/main/java/my.app/...
we have our generated code within target/generated-sources/my/app/restinterfaces/..

(Example package structure below)
We have the generated API-interfaces and models in a package restinterfaces and we want to allow access to this package from our domainA and domainB packages.
Normally, we would do this via @org.springframework.modulith.NamedInterface in the package-info.java - files. How would we solve this in our case where a package only exists in a generated package-structure.


From an architectural perspective, the ideal way to tweak this is to make sure that OpenAPI generates the API and DTO classes into the modules they belong, as a web API logically belongs to the module.
A (rather ugly) workaround would be to declare a package-info.java in my.app.restinterfaces within src/main/java and annotate that with @ApplicationModule(type = Type.OPEN). This would cause any code inside that package to be accessibly to other application modules.
That said, this kind of violates the idea that a module is self-contained, i.e., any kind of technology adapters would reside within modules, and not outside of it in a global bucket.
